# c# Mysql select value where a and b are devidable

Tags: c#, mysql

Hello guys I am googling for long time, so I decided to get help from here I am trying to find Row where
collumn A value is dividable from B value. Help me out. It should look like this:

```
string select = "Select Suma FROM ivykiai WHERE (`Ivikio diena` ~?Is dividable?~ Periodiskumas_d";
```

What should I write in ~?Is dividable?~ ?

Comment: investigate the modulus operator. if the result is an integer, it's dividable. 10 % 2 = 5, 10%10 = 0 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the modulo operator, `%`.

When `a%b` the `a` is divided by `b`.

This in term of your code is can be done like below:

```
string select = "Select Suma FROM ivykiai WHERE `Ivikio diena`%Periodiskumas_d=0";
```

For further documentation about this operator, please have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_mod).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a modulo operator, see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod

So you can write a query like `SELECT ... WHERE A MOD B = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [mod operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod):

```
string select = "Select Suma FROM ivykiai WHERE (`Ivikio diena` % Periodiskumas_d = 0)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sql MOD() function:

```
Select Suma FROM ivykiai WHERE (mod('Ivikio diena','Periodiskumas_d'))=0
```